# X11vnc server exits when I close tightVNC viewer

Tags: x11, beagleboard, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I followed this blog to set up a VNC connection from my Windows 8 laptop to my BeagleBone Black.

[Digital Diner: Quick hint for Beaglebone Black user](http://digitaldiner.blogspot.com/2013/05/quick-hint-for-beaglebone-black-user.html)

It works well except for one problem: the X11VNC server on the Beagle Bone Black exits when I close the TightVNC Viewer on my laptop. I have to connect a remote terminal to the BBB using PuTTY and run the command given in the blog in order to reconnect.

Any suggestions on how to keep the server from exiting when I close the TightVNC viewer connection on my laptop? Is there a way to always have the X11vnc server running on the Beagle Bone Black so I can connect anytime?

Answer (score 13):

I found the answer here: [BeagleBone Black Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/beagleboard/beaglebone-black/t7SO106MYnM).

The key is to add -forever to the end of the command to start the X11vnc server.

x11vnc -bg -o %HOME/.x11vnc.log.%VNCDISPLAY -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm*/database -display :0 - forever - nopw

I also added this command to the start up applications. System --> Preferences --> Startup Applications